# How to start a new thread in channel with a Proactive Channel Dialog?

Tags: botframework

My bot can create a new thread in a channel like [this](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/58.teams-start-new-thread-in-channel/Bots/TeamsStartNewThreadInTeam.cs). Now I want to start a proactive dialog in this new thread. I am starting the dialog in a subsequent `ContinueConversationAsync` callback. The dialog seems to start, but as soon as a user is prompted, the users reply is not handled by the dialog but the MainDialog.

If I initiate the dialog with a user sent activity, then the dialog handles prompts correctly. Only the proactive dialog does not seem to work in a newly created channel.

This is my code

```
var conversationParameters = new ConversationParameters
{
    IsGroup = true,
    ChannelData = new TeamsChannelData
    {
        Channel = new ChannelInfo(teamsChannelId)
    },
    Activity = (Activity)message
};

ConversationReference newConversationReference = null;
await adapter.CreateConversationAsync(
    teamsChannelId,
    serviceUrl,
    credentials,
    conversationParameters,
    (t, c) =>
    {
        newConversationReference = t.Activity.GetConversationReference();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }, cancellationToken);


await adapter.ContinueConversationAsync(
    _appId,
    newConversationReference,
    async (t, c) =>
    {
        var dialogStateAccessor = this.conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState));
        var dialogState = await dialogStateAccessor.GetAsync(t, () => new DialogState());

        var dialogSet = new DialogSet(dialogStateAccessor);
        dialogSet.Add(dialog);
        var dialogContext = await dialogSet.CreateContextAsync(t, cancellationToken);
        await dialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(dialog.Id, options, cancellationToken);
        await conversationState.SaveChangesAsync(t, false, cancellationToken);
    },
    cancellationToken);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please include the code that starts your `MainDialog` as well as the actual code for your `MainDialog`. I believe what's happening is that in `OnMessageAsync`, all messages are being routed to `MainDialog` instead of the currently active dialog. You may need something like [`DialogExtensions`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/44a050f4e350c5d3b760dfba6c45f2acad44d757/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/adaptive-dialog/01.multi-turn-prompt/DialogExtensions.cs)

Comment: I had the problem you described very early in my project. In order to get proactive dialoges working at all I had to create a DialogSet with all my dialogs in. Only then the users reponses to go to the right dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Problem was that I took the `ConversationReference` from the the callback of the newly created channel post and tried to use that in `ContinueConverationAsync()`. That `ConversationReference` however is not enough. So I merged my original `ConversationReference` with the new `ConversationReference` and used that instead. Now it works like a charm.

Here is my updated code:

```
ConversationReference newConversationReference = null;
await adapter.CreateConversationAsync(
    conversationChannelId,
    serviceUrl,
    credentials,
    conversationParameters,
    (t, c) =>
    {
        newConversationReference = t.Activity.GetConversationReference();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }, cancellationToken);

if (dialog != null)
{
    // Proactive channel dialogs dont seem to work with the newConversationReference: responses to the dialog are handled by the MainDialog.
    // So I just create a new ConversationReference from the topic subscription and the new conversation. That works.
    var newNewConversationReference = new ConversationReference
    {
        ActivityId = newConversationReference.ActivityId,
        Bot = conversationReference.Bot,
        ChannelId = conversationReference.ChannelId,
        ServiceUrl = conversationReference.ServiceUrl,
        User = conversationReference.User,
        Conversation = new ConversationAccount
        {
            Id = newConversationReference.Conversation.Id,
            AadObjectId = conversationReference.Conversation.AadObjectId,
            ConversationType = conversationReference.Conversation.ConversationType,
            IsGroup = conversationReference.Conversation.IsGroup,
            Name = conversationReference.Conversation.Name,
            Properties = conversationReference.Conversation.Properties,
            TenantId = conversationReference.Conversation.TenantId,
            Role = conversationReference.Conversation.Role,
        },
    };

    await adapter.ContinueConversationAsync(
        _appId,
        newNewConversationReference,
        async (t, c) =>
        {
            var dialogStateAccessor = this.conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState));
            var dialogState = await dialogStateAccessor.GetAsync(t, () => new DialogState());

            var dialogSet = new DialogSet(dialogStateAccessor);
            dialogSet.Add(dialog);
            var dialogContext = await dialogSet.CreateContextAsync(t, cancellationToken);
            await dialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(dialog.Id, options, cancellationToken);
            await conversationState.SaveChangesAsync(t, false, cancellationToken);
        },
        cancellationToken);
}
```